# Регулярные выражения, сортировка слов по кол-ву гласных

Tags: java, ооп

Как без г-внокода сделать так, чтобы можно было искать по большему количеству гласных, а не только по одной?

Входная строка: Аааая аа ааа я
Выходная: я аа ааа Аааая 
По заданию нужно отсортировать слова по количеству гласных

Делается это как-то через регулярку, но как что-то идей не приходит в голову

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    private static class ByLetterMeetings implements Comparator<String> {
        private char letter;

    ByLetterMeetings(char l) {
        letter = l;
    }
    int matchesCount(String s) {
        int found = 0;

        for ( char c : s.toCharArray() )
            if ( letter == c )
                ++found;

        return found;
    }

    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        int diff = matchesCount(a) - matchesCount(b);
        return ( diff != 0 ) ? diff : a.compareTo(b);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "а ааа аа";
    String[] words = s.split(" ");
    Arrays.sort(words, new ByLetterMeetings('а'));
    for ( String w : words )
        System.out.println(w);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярка здесь необязательна. Можно заменить проверку

```
if ( letter == c )
```

на

```
if (c == 'а' || c == 'о' || c == 'е' || ...)
```

Получится более-менее нормально, ещё короче это можно записать с помощью метода [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-), который возвращает индекс вхождения символа в строку:

```
if ("уеыаоэяию".indexOf(c) != -1)
```

Comment: Неочень хорошее решение
String s = "ЯЯ ЯЯЯ ааа аа ЯЯЯяяяяя";

Вывод:
ЯЯ
ЯЯЯ
аа
ааа
ЯЯЯяяяяя

Comment: @NameJ, скажи, пожалуйста, ты ведь понимаешь, почему в этом случае не работает?

Comment: Мой косяк."УЕЫАОЭЯИЮуеыаоэяию" :)